# Listing directory contents with for loop and ls

Tags: bash, shell

I cannot get this bash loop to list the contents of all directories that match the pattern:

```
for f in `ls -d -1 visc*`; do ls $f; done
```

I cannot understand why this is not working. During execution of the command I get errors such as

```
ls: cannot access visc_vm3_s00: No such file or directory
```

for each item that matches the pattern. But these directories are obviously there. Infact if I do

```
folders="visc_vm3_s00 visc_vm3_s01 visc_vm3_s02"
for f in $folders; do ls $f; done
```

then this works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The problem probably lies on how `ls -d1 visc*` is expanded, or on its output. What do you get if you do for f in `ls -d -1 visc*`; do echo "$f" | hexdump -C; echo; done?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with file permissions? ``*`` is expanded with some filenames that cannot be accessed by ``ls``

Comment: I would try `for d in visc*/; do` first, and if a problem remains, debug that. It's really not worth debugging the original approach.

Comment: What do you see with `for f in \`ls -d -1 visc*\`; do echo "<$f>"; done`?

Comment: Why not just `ls visc*/`? Let the shell do the expansion for you - it's pretty good at that...

Comment: @chepner That worked! I should add that the problem I state in my question occurs on bash in CentOS. Otherwise the code in my question works perfectly on Mac.

Comment: Spaces in file/dir names? If so then you'd need 'ls "$f"'

Comment: Apparently the issue occurred because my `ls` was aliased to `ls --color`. Removing the color option resolved the issue regarding the original question.

Comment: Alias ls to `ls --color=tty` and you won't have a problem.